# Can't get a FORM to submit remotely in Rails 3.0.3?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I am using Rails 3.0.3 with jQuery ujs.

I want to send a form remotely. The view template **mains/index.html.erb** containing the form looks as follows:

```
...
<%= form_tag :remote => true, :controller => "mains", :action => "search", :format => :js do %>
<div class="dialog">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="prop">
<td valign="top" class="name">
 <%= label_tag(:location_start, "Location Start:") %>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<%= text_field_tag(:location_start) %>
</td>
...
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<span class="button"><%= submit_tag("Search") %></span>
</div>
<% end %>
...
```

The controller **mains_controller.rb** looks as follows (removed unnecessary stuff):

```
class MainsController < ApplicationController

def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
  end
end

def search
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :template => 'mains/search.js.erb'}
  end
end

end
```

The view template **mains/search.js.erb** has the following content:

```
$('#search').html("<h1>Headline</h1>");
```

I am using search.js.erb instead of search.js.rjs due to instructions in chapter "26.4 Write Less and Do More with JQuery" in Agile Web Development with Rails (4h edition). I also added **:format => :js** due to https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/closed/#issue/52.

When I call **http://0.0.0.0:3000/mains/index** and submit the form, it's actually not submitted remotely, but the browser loads **http://0.0.0.0:3000/mains/search.js?remote=true** instead. The browser outputs `$('#search').html("<h1>Headline</h1>");`, instead of executing the JavaScript by replacing div#search with `<h1>Headline</h1>` given.

I tried to find a solution but wasen't successful so far... Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by replacing `<%= form_tag :remote => true, :controller => "mains", :action => "search", :format => :js do %>` with `<%= form_tag( {:controller => "mains", :action => "search"}, :remote => true ) do %>` and updating to the newest version of jQuery ujs...

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution for everyone else!